# Upgrade package that was installed with apt-get to version in .deb file

Tags: apt, software-installation, dpkg

I have installed a package with `apt-get install package`. I will now have to upgrade to a newer version that is only available as `package.deb` from the vendor's web site.

So how can I go about upgrading a package that was installed with `apt-get` with `dpkg` (after downloading the `.deb` file)?

One option that comes to mind is `apt-get remove package && dpkg --install package.deb`, but this seems sub-optimal e.g. because it can run into [difficulties](https://superuser.com/questions/196864/how-to-install-local-deb-packages-with-apt-get/698249) when `package.deb` adds new dependencies. Is there a better way to go?

Comment: If the package is actually an upgrade (keeps the same name, maintainer scripts can handle previous version), then you don't need to remove it. But this is not always the case if the new package comes from the vendor (who may or may not respect the existing package's conventions of names, versions, file locations, etc.).

Comment: I agree with @muru .. I've just `dpkg -i` installed any upgrades if its not in a repo|ppa without issues with the few apps I've had to upgrade on debian|ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

Download the new version of your software, `cd` into its directory and then simply run:

```
sudo apt install package.deb
```

The `apt` utility can handle installing `.deb` files while handling their dependencies too.

Just make sure the `package.deb` that you are downloading has been created for your Ubuntu version, for example do not install a `deb` file which is created for `zesty` on `xenial`.

Comment: does this then install the dependencies as well? What happens if the apt repo version at some point in time catches up with the version from the deb?

Comment: It also installs the dependencies (if they exist in the repositories). If the version catches up in some point, it gets replaced with the newer version unless you hold the package using apt-mark.